# Get username from jwt Express app

Tags: node.js, rest, express, authentication, jwt

I have 3 routes in my code , for Users, for Products and For Orders.
I use jwt and generate tokens for users, and I want to assign orders to token Owners.
Here's my Order Model :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ,
  product: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
  quantity: {type: Number , default: 1},
  user_name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

And here's my middleware to check Authenticate (It's imported as checkAuth) :

```
module.exports = (req,res,next) => {
  try {
    var decoded = jwt.verify(req.headers.token, secretjwt);
    req.userData = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      'error': 'Auth Failed',
      'details': error.message
    });
  }
```

Here's my post api for adding orders, What Should I write as user_name to assign it to the user (I don't want to get username as a body parameter)?

```
router.post('/newOrder', checkAuth, (req,res,next) => {
  var order = new Order({
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    product: req.body.productId,
    user_name: // WHAT SHOULD IT BE?
  });
  order.save()
  .then(result => {
    res.status(200).json(result);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.json(200);
  });

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

> req.userData = decoded
>   put
>   req.body.userData = decoded

And put user_name: req.body.userData in following snip

```html
router.post('/newOrder', checkAuth, (req,res,next) => {
  var order = new Order({
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    product: req.body.productId,
    user_name: // WHAT SHOULD IT BE?
  });
  order.save()
  .then(result => {
    res.status(200).json(result);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.json(200);
  });

});
```